# How do you bind attributes in an enyo kind?

Tags: enyo

I am having problems creating a Tweet() kind instance and having the span content be "hoho" even though line 60 should set it - https://github.com/metaperl/enyo-identica-tutorial/blob/master/source/App.js#L60

I also tried `t.setText("hoho");` but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `setText()` instead of violating the encapsulation of the tweet kind.  However, the problem appears to be the call to `addContent()`.  This doesn't do what you think it should.  Either you want to call `addContent()` with `t.getText()` or you want to actually add the new tweet control to the scroller.  `addContent()` expects to get a string passed in (see:  http://enyojs.com/api/#enyo.Control).

You probably want to instead do something like this:

```
reloadTweets: function() {
    this.$.main.createComponent({kind: "Tweet", text: "hohoho"}, {owner: this});
    this.$.main.render();
}
```

Although, what you probably -really- want to do is directly add tweets to the scroller or create a flyweight list and add the items to that.

Comment: is the `main` in `main.createComponent` referring to the component named "main" that is a component of the FittableRows App?

Comment: Whoops, I left off this.$.  I will edit to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/comment/8136/#Comment_8136) which is close to Pre101's suggestion.

Here is my working code:

```
reloadTweets: function(inSender, inEvent) {
    this.$.main.createComponent({
        kind: "Tweet",
        text: "ho ho ho ho"
    });
    this.render();
}
```